# How to authenticate a REST or Web request without a logged in user?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, authentication

We have a requirement to support non-authenticated requests. For eg: displaying information on a page that is sent out as an email link. In this case, the end user who is clicking on the link is not an user in our backend system. However, this page displayed will have few REST calls to our backend and returns data.

But we want to make sure we have some kind of check (something like a token that doesn't expire at all) to avoid requests submitted by just knowing the URLs for the above REST calls. I am not sure of what needs to be done in such cases. Hope my question is clear and make sense.

Our back end server is Spring and we use Spring Security for user authentication.

Comment: Consider asking this on https://security.stackexchange.com/. Generally, you could just include a (perhaps recipient-specific) token in the URL, e.g. `http://mysvc.any/view?token=123ABCdef`, which is submitted with the REST requests in a special header field.You should also include the possibility to invalidate some of these tokens server-side once abuse is detected.

Comment: You might want to take a quick look at Spring security baeldung tutorial., am thinking ur looking at something like login page as in the tutorial. http://www.baeldung.com/securing-a-restful-web-service-with-spring-security